# Probability function (Very simple indoor positioning system)

Tags: probability, functions

I am a programmer, I am working on a masters thesis, tts an Android application, where I will need to implement a  very simple indoor positioning system using WiFi RSS. The number of routers is fixed. The idea is to measure decibels of each router in given room. So the room can be defined by a quintuple of values.

Now the user starts the application and makes a reading of the quintuple defined by his current position.

What I now need to figure out is, which of the rooms am I most likely in. Any idea how to do this? Steer me in right direction, please, as math is not really my strong point.

Thanks !

Comment: There is a lot of vagueness in your post. Can you clarify the settings. What is this quintuple or how many routers, rooms etc.

Comment: The idea is to track people inside school and trigger some event if they enter some predifined room. 

The rooms will not be close to each other, only those the teacher visits as he teaches

The quintuple is just a example, I dont know how many routers will there be, but the count will be fixed and they also will not move.

Lets say (10,20,30,40,50) defines room A, what I need is to find what technique or algorithm assigns measurment of, for example, (9,20,30,40,50) to the room A. (also I think the signals vary, so more then one measurement will be made as to define the room)

Comment: I am sorry, but the information you have provided is still inadequate for me to help you. I hope someone else can help you. Good luck!

Comment: k-nearest neighbours seems to be what I am looking for...